# Is the Golden God Achievement still possible with wrath of the Lamb?

Tags: achievements, the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

Can I still get the Golden God! achievement in Wrath of the Lamb or will I only get it when I get the Platinum God! too?

The description of both achievements is: "100% of the game" but Golden God! was available before Wrath of the Lamb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I had not yet achieved Golden God when I upgraded to Wrath of the Lamb, but after finishing the original game achievements I did receive it. I did not have to finish all the Wrath of the Lamb achievements.